# My generic method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I don't know where is the problem. I have created a generic method that given a List, a rank of values (E[]) and a Comparator it returns a Set with the values of the list that are inside that rank but without using For, while etc.

My method could be wrong cause I haven't be able to execute and debug it, but I think the problem is in the header. Here is the code:

```
public class Ejercicio3 {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Map<List<Integer>, int[]> dicc = lecturaFichero("./ficheros/PI2Ej3DatosEntrada.txt");
    muestraDiccionarioConArray(dicc);
    Comparator<Integer> comp = Comparator.naturalOrder();
    for(Entry<List<Integer>,int[]> pareja:dicc.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> lista = pareja.getKey();
        int[] rango = pareja.getValue();
        ejercicio3R(lista, rango, comp);

    }
}

public static <E> Set<E> ejercicio3R(List<E> lista, E[] rango, Comparator<E> comp) {
    return ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, 0, lista.size()-1);
}

public static <E> Set<E> ejercicio3RG(List<E> lista, E[] rango, Comparator<E> comp, int i, int j) {
    Set<E> acum = new HashSet<>();
    boolean aEnRango = false; boolean bEnRango = false; boolean cEnRango = false; boolean dEnRango = false;
    int tamLista = j-i+1;
    int tamMitad = tamLista/2;
    E a; E b; E c; E d; //elemento central izq, central dcho, extremo izq, extremo dcho.
    int posa; int posb;
    E ra = rango[0]; E rb = rango[1];
    if((tamMitad)%2==0) {
        posa = tamMitad+i-1; posb = tamMitad+i;
    } else {
        posa = tamMitad+i; posb = tamMitad+i+1;
    }
    a = lista.get(posa);
    b = lista.get(posb);
    c = lista.get(i);
    d = lista.get(j);
    //compruebo si los dos elementos centrales se encuentran dentro del rango, en dicho caso son incluidos dentro del conjunto.
    if(comp.compare(a, ra)>=0&&comp.compare(a, rb)<1) {
        acum.add(a);
        aEnRango = true;
    } else if(comp.compare(b, ra)>=0&&comp.compare(b, rb)<1) {
        acum.add(b);
        bEnRango = true;
    } else if(comp.compare(c, ra)>=0&&comp.compare(c, rb)<1) {
        acum.add(c);
        cEnRango = true;
    } else if(comp.compare(c, ra)>=0&&comp.compare(c, rb)<1) {
        acum.add(d);
        dEnRango = true;
    }
    //si ambos valores se encuentran dentro del rango divido en dos listas. Salvo que a sea el extremo izquierdo
    //del intervalo, en dicho caso no miro a la izquierda, porque la lista está ordenada y esos valores estarían 
    //fuera del intervalo. Al tener el rango intervalo abierto por la derecha no puedo hacer esta comprobación con
    //b. Porque no sé la cota máxima por la derecha (en el caso de int sería rb-1, pero es un código genérico.
    if(cEnRango&&dEnRango) {
    //si los extremos están en el rango. TODOS los elementos de la lista se encuentran en el rango
        acum = lista.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } else if(aEnRango&&bEnRango) {                             
        //si ambos valores se encuentran dentro del rango divido en dos listas. Salvo que a sea el extremo izquierdo
        //del intervalo, en dicho caso no miro a la izquierda, porque la lista está ordenada y esos valores estarían 
        //fuera del intervalo. Al tener el rango intervalo abierto por la derecha no puedo hacer esta comprobación con
        //b. Porque no sé la cota máxima por la derecha (en el caso de int sería rb-1, pero es un código genérico.
        if(comp.compare(a, ra)==0) {
            acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, posb+1, j);
        } else {
            acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, i, posa-1);
            acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, posb+1, j);
        }
    } else if(aEnRango) {
        acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, i, posa-1);
    } else if(bEnRango) {
        acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, posb+1, j);
    } else {
        //si a es menor que la cota izq. significa que los elementos del rango estarán a la derecha. Y como b tampoco está dentro del rango,
        //dividiremos a partir de él
        if(comp.compare(a, ra)<0) { 
            acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, posb+1, j);
        //si a es mayor que la cota izquierda los elementos del rango estarán en la parte izquierda a no inclusive. 
        } else {
            acum = ejercicio3RG(lista, rango, comp, i, posa-1);
        }
    }
    return acum;
}
```

The other methods work nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are declared as

```
List<E> lista, E[] rango, Comparator<E> comp
```

And you pass

```
lista, rango, comp
```

which are of type

```
List<Integer>, int[], Comparator<Integer>
```

See, It should be the same type everywhere, but instead of `Integer[]`, you pass an `int[]`. That's not the same type.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works!.  May you explain me why it works with Integer[], but not with int[]?. Thx

Comment: if List<E> is List<Integer> and Comparator<E> is COmparator<Integer>, then E[] should be Integer[]. Why do you think int should work? int isn't even a reference type, so it can't be used for a generic type.